# Riemann integrability given by limit of $\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n[f(k/n)]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is such that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n[f(k/n)] = 1,$$

does that imply that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is $N$ in this case?

Comment: (if $f$ is Riemann integrable) this is exactly the definition of the Riemann integral $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dirichlet function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } x\in \mathbb Q \\ 0 & \text{if } x\notin \mathbb Q \end{cases}$$

satisfies the condition but is not Riemann integrable.